# How to connect Dynamo db with express angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I create simple angular 7 form and backend express node app now I want to store data into Database(Dynamodb) so how I connect it with my application that takes inputs from frontend and store data into db

```
    app.post('/business/add', (req, res) => {
var table = "business";
var person_name = req.body.person_name;
var business_name = req.body.business_name;
var business_gst_number = req.body.business_gst_number;

var params = {
    Item: {
        "person_name": {
       S: person_name

      }, 
      "business_name": {
       S: business_name
      }, 
      "business_gst_number": {
       N: business_gst_number
      }
    }, 
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL", 
    TableName: "business"
   };


console.log("Adding a new item...");
doClient.putitem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});

    // console.log(req.body);
    // res.json({});
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Angular http service to make request to the server (localhost/ip/domain).
[Angular Http](https://angular.io/guide/http)

On server side configure aws-sdk.[Configure aws-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)

Once aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key are configured you can make connection to DynamoDb

Refer this official Dynamo db docs for nodejs for CRUD ops.
[DynamoDb Nodejs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.html)

Comment: i did this , post req working with console.log(req.body); but if i take data from frontend then error i think there is error in api

Comment: POST http://localhost:4000/business/add 500 (Internal Server Error) and  another error is http response error , only working with simple post req having console